# spring:message in Jquery function

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

¿Is possible to pass data from a variable in jquery, to a element in a jsp with spring:message tag?

Something like this:

```
var url1="http://some.org/some.json";
 $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            var url3 = data.homepageURL; 
            <c:if test="${not empty prot.code}"><p><label><spring:message code="website"/>:</label><a href=url3>url3</a></p></c:if>
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The jsp code is run on server side. The code is already execute at the time the javascript is running in the browser.

You need to use javascript to update your page from the ajax callback. You could add the jsp tags at the rigth place in your document, give the a tag you want to fill with url3 an id and the later use javascript to set the text for the a tag.